# Why does my fill go outside the path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, fill

[image: here how it looks]

So I just want to fill that path with color but this happens. When it is not filled or in 0% opacity, it looks really normal, no doubled edges or things. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: It's hard to tell without inspecting how the path is made. Have you tried to test if it's a GPU rendering problem? Try switching to CPU rendering and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Otherwise. Show us the effects panel.

Comment: Or perhaps share the AI file.

Comment: @Wolff I changed to "Preview on CPU" but nothing has changed.

Comment: @jooja do you mean [there?](https://imgur.com/a/jFCP6xf)

Comment: @BillyKerr [here you go](https://disk.yandex.com.tr/i/lfK4dw2lscaZAA)

Comment: @pofdzm - there are 8 copies of the shape all on top of each other.  This suggests operator error. Nothing to do with Illustrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened your pdf file in Illustrator.

Select your image and go to Object> Compound Path> Release

Then open your layers panel and you will see 3 separate Paths

Each of those 3 Paths have 3 Transform Effects applied and this is causing your trouble. You can see these in the Appearance Panel. I toggled off the visibility for 2 of the paths in the Layers Panel and selected the other visible Path. Open the Appearance Panel and toggle off the visibility for the 3 Transform effects that have been applied- I would simply delete those Transform Effects for each of your 3 paths.

Then your Fill will precisely follow your path outlines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i realized how it happened. I wanted to turn a shape symmetrical by copying the right half and reflecting it to the left half, a website suggested me the transform effect, i thought it worked without realizing something like that happened. Though, can you help me with making the shape symmetrical without messing up the shape? As I said, I want to copy the right part and reflect it to the left part.

Comment: This should really be a separate question and answer- so that someone else searching how to do this would be able to find it as well. Simple version is to set a vertical guide centered on where you want to reflect. Remove the half you do not want, then use the reflect tool and alt/option click anywhere on the guide. A dialog box will open where you can choose which way you want it reflected and also choose to copy your original side. Then use the join command to join the 2 halves. This is simplified but should get you going in the right direction.